# How to run an app when it does not show under Apps?

Tags: android, debugging, installation, adb

I used `ant` to build my Eclipse project from the command line in a debug configuration. (Eclipse Luna and Android NDK-R10d is broken, so I can't use Eclipse any longer. Confer, [Eclipse/ADT plugin cannot locate symbols for r10d NDK](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=97023)).

I then performed an install using `adb`:

```
<Project Directory>$ adb install bin/AndroidPrng-debug.apk
```

When I rummage for the program on the device in Apps, the program is *not* offered. When I attempt to search for it by name on the device (`AndroidPrng` and `com.example.prng`), I'm provided with useless web search results. When I go to *Settings → Apps*, the app is shown under the *Downloaded* tab (it shows the name as `com.example.prng`). It has the familiar Force Stop and Uninstall.

I have DDMS running and waiting to capture LogCat output from the program. But even though the app is on the device, I cannot figure out how to run it.

How do I run and debug the app when it does not show up under Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your app do have an Activity from where you can navigate into other parts of your app.

Try using below command:

```
$ adb shell am start -n com.example.yourpackagename/.YourMainActivity
```

or
 `$ adb shell am start -n com.package.yourpackagename/com.example.yourpackagename.YourMainActivity`

This `am start` command, is a command-line interface to the ActivityManager.

Comment: Thanks @MeTechnical. I renamed the APK from `AndroidPrng-debug.apk` to `AndroidPrng.apk` and it showed up under Apps. Damn I hate this sort of development....